# Let $B$ be a matrix such that..

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, inverse

$B=\begin{bmatrix}1&2x&-13\\1&2x+2&2x-13\\1&2x+6&7x+6\end{bmatrix}$ , $x$ is a parameter. 
there exists a $y,z\in\mathbb{R}$ such that for this system theres a solution: 
$B^{43}\begin{bmatrix}-285\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix} $ 
$x=?$ 

I can't somehow get around how to solve this question, I know that it has something to do with inverse matrices and I know that if the matrix is invertible then $r(B)=3$, which means theres a unique answer for the equation $Bx=0$. 
 
Any help or hints are really appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $y$ and $z$ can be anything, the condition is equivalent to the fact that $B^{43}$ has nontrivial kernel, which means it is noninvertible. Now $B^{43}$ is noninvertible if and only if $B$ is noninvertible so you need precisely those $x \in \Bbb{R}$ such that $\det B = 0$.

We have $$0 = \det B = 2x+38 \implies x = -19.$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I still haven't learnt about det, but from your answer, I can reach row echelon form of $B$ and choose $x$ so I get a zero row, and since $r(B)<3$ then we will get infinite solutions. is this also true?

Comment: @Pwaol Yes, the row echelon form is $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2x & -13 \\ 0 & 2 & 2x \\ 0 & 0 & x+19\end{bmatrix}$$
which is noninvertible if and only if the last row is zero i.e. $x=-19$.

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help.